# Get Last ActivityDate for a group of Accounts

Tags: apex, soql

I have a list of accounts that I need to get the last meeting that has been held with each account. Unfortunately the following SOQL doesn't work. I get the following error: "field ActivityDate does not support operator MAX

```
SELECT WhatId, MAX(ActivityDate) 
FROM Task 
WHERE Type = 'Meeting' AND WhatId in :accountIds
GROUP BY WhatId
```

I don't really want to select all activities and loop through them to find the max for each account. Any other solutions?

Comment: There is an idea for adding aggregate operations on ActivityDate now. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lJtWQAU

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this would do the trick

```
SELECT id, (select activitydate from tasks
            where type = 'Meeting'
            order by activitydate desc limit 1)
FROM Account
WHERE ID in :accountIds
```

Comment: Thanks! Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: It's been a long week - sometimes you need a second pair of eyes. Glad it helped.